# Can limits be defined in a more algebraic way, instead of using the completely analytic $\delta$-$\epsilon$ definition?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, limits, definition

> Let $(X,d_X), (Y,d_Y)$ be metric spaces. Let $f:E\subseteq X\to Y$ and $a\in X$.
>
> We say that $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=L$ if and only if for every $\epsilon >0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that $d_Y(f(x),L)<\epsilon$ whenever $0<d_X(x,a)<\delta$.

This is the textbook definition you'll see in many analysis books. The notion of continuity in a metric space is most of the times defined using limits.

However, a more general (topological) definition of continuity can be stated:

> $f:X\to Y$ is continuous if and only if the preimage of every open set $V\subseteq Y$ is open.

---

I'm looking for a nice definition like that one for limits. One that doesn't have the typical $\epsilon$-$\delta$ style.

Is such a thing possible?

Comment: I don't see how this topological definition of continuity is 'nice' (I would say it is more 'obfuscated' than 'nice')

Comment: @user1952009: It’s extremely nice: it’s simple, elegant, and often very easy to work with.

Comment: @user1952009 To add to Brian Scott's comment: This definition doesn't require **at all** a formal notion of distance.

Comment: @Brian : I'd say that you don't understand what means "maths are about concepts". it is easy to work with concepts, it is impossible to work with definitions which aren't related to any known concept. of course, the continuity concept is related to the concept of distance and of neighborhoods inclusion, much less to the concept of openness of sets

Comment: @user1952009 Well, then  you'd be losing out a pretty important part of topology: the notion of a topological space (see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_space).

Comment: @user1952009: On the contrary, in the general topological setting the concept of continuity is very strongly related to the concept of openness of sets, and there generally isn’t any notion of distance.

Comment: I think both the approaches of using "distance" (metric spaces) and using "open sets" (topological spaces) are very useful generalizations of the concepts of limits and continuity as studied in beginner's calculus. The main motive behind these two generalizations seems to be figure out how much (or how far) the concepts of calculus can be carried off if we don't restrict to specific properties of $\mathbb{R}$ (set of reals).

Answer (score 1):

In some settings you can define limits in a covariant fashion, thereby making the definition considerably more intuitive:

> $\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(x)=L$ if and only if $f$ takes every point close to $a$ (in some well-defined sense) to a point close to $L$ (in the same sense).

For example, take a look at the Wikipedia article on [*near sets*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near_sets) and, especially, at the paper P. Cameron, J.G. Hocking, and S.A. Naimpally, [*Nearness — A Better Approach to Continuity and Limits*](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2319561?origin=crossref&seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents): once you have the appropriate notion of nearness, you can say that the limit of $f$ at $a$ is $L$ if $f(x)$ is near $L$ whenever $x$ is near $a$.

Much the same sort of thing can be done in the setting of non-standard analysis: the limit of $f$ at $a$ is $L$ if the hyperreal extension $f^*$ of $f$ takes points infinitely close to $a$ to points infinitely close to $L$.

Answer (score 0):

We can get a definition like this for limits of sequences: $a_n$ converges to $a$ if every open set containing $a$ also contains all but finitely many of the terms of $a_n$. For limits of  functions, we can say that $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)=L$ if $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(a_n)=L$ whenever $a_n$ is a sequence converging to $L$.

Answer (score 0):

Well, once limits in $\Bbb R$ are known, we can reduce the things to *sequences* and limits only in $\Bbb R$:

1. $a_n\to a$ in a metric space iff $d(a_n,a)\to 0$.
2. $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)=b$ iff for all $x_n\to a$ we have $f(x_n)\to b$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $f : X \to Y$ is a map between two topological spaces (not necessarily continuous); $a \in X$; and $L \in Y$.  We have that $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = L$ if and only if whenever $U \subseteq Y$ is a neighborhood of $L$, then $f^{-1}(U)$ is a possibly punctured neighborhood of $a$.  Here, we define $V \subseteq X$ to be a possibly punctured neighborhood of $a$ if there is some open neighborhood $W$ of $a$ such that $W \setminus \{ a \} \subseteq V$ - or equivalently, if $V \cup \{ a \}$ is a neighborhood of $a$.

(Note that, just as the set of neighborhoods of $L$ forms a filter on $Y$, so also the set of possibly punctured neighborhoods of $a$ forms a filter on $X$ assuming that $a$ is not an isolated point in $X$.  This leads naturally to ways of expressing other familiar limit statements from real analysis in terms of relations between a filter on $Y$ and a filter on $X$.  For example, for $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, we can say $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x) = \infty$ if and only if $f^{-1}(S) \in \mathscr{F}_{\infty}$  for every $S \in \mathscr{F}_\infty$, where $\mathscr{F}_\infty$ is the filter on $\mathbb{R}$ consisting of sets $S$ such that $S \supseteq [N, \infty)$ for some $N \in \mathbb{R}$.)